# How to know if user touch the marker in Google map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I need to know if user touch the marker.

[image]

Any idea? I hope that somebody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement [`OnMarkerClickListner`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html) and override `onMarkerClick` method.

Hava a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#marker_events)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code below inside onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){..}

```
mMap = googleMap;
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Log.e("Testing",marker.getTitle());
        return false;
    }
});
```